# Resources$NotFoundException MenuItemImpl

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Crash occurs on 0.1% from total users on different devices, different android versions.

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: 
  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue (ResourcesImpl.java:201)
  at android.content.res.MiuiResourcesImpl.getValue (MiuiResourcesImpl.java:95)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue (Resources.java:1304)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.createDrawableIfNeeded (ResourceManagerInternal.java:176)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java:141)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable (ResourceManagerInternal.java:132)
  at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable (AppCompatResources.java:104)
  at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon (MenuItemImpl.java:505)
  at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.initialize (ActionMenuItemView.java:126)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.bindItemView (ActionMenuPresenter.java:207)
  at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.getItemView (BaseMenuPresenter.java:188)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.getItemView (ActionMenuPresenter.java:193)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.flagActionItems (ActionMenuPresenter.java:473)
  at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.flagActionItems (MenuBuilder.java:1182)
  at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.updateMenuView (BaseMenuPresenter.java:96)
  at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.updateMenuView (ActionMenuPresenter.java:226)
  at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchPresenterUpdate (MenuBuilder.java:298)
  at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.onItemsChanged (MenuBuilder.java:1069)
  at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.startDispatchingItemsChanged (MenuBuilder.java:1096)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.preparePanel (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1778)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.doInvalidatePanelMenu (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2016)
  at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$2.run (AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:253)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:754)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:165)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6375)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygo
```

Crash happens in menu creation method.
menu.xml:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="share"
        app:showAsAction="always" />


</menu>
```

Standart method:

```
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
 }
```

I have different ic_share.png in drawable folders: nodpi, mdpi, hdpi, xdpi, xxdpi, xxxdpi

My environment:

1. gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
2. classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
3. android studio 3.4.1
4. compileSdkVersion 28
5. targetSdkVersion 28

Please help.

Comment: Hi, have you been able to resolve this issue? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

check your drawable if they are not set only for one sdk version.

Comment: No, I don't use versioned folders like v21 or something like this